# How to make countdown timer as a background for my website

Tags: html, css, background, countdown

First time using this site and quite new  to html and css so excuse me if I am not asking in the correct way. So, I have the following problem. I have a hero background image with full with i want to put a countdown timer over it but then I want a "Coming Soon" text over the countdown timer. The countdown should be with full with and with 50% or less opacity so it will be kida like a background to the "Coming Soon" text if you understand me. The question is how to put the Coming Soon text over the countdown timer?
Thanks

Comment: You are new, you must know when you register on the page a help-tour is suggested. Please refer to the help center and learn how to ask. **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**

Comment: How large do you want the background, and where do you want it? Also please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to assign the body or html tag to have your background image, then position DIV tags that have positioning to desired locations inside the body section.

You can position the divs over eachother with the margin property as it can do negative positions if needed.